# Azure to reject SAS tokens not issued using Stored Access Policies

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a way to get Azure to reject SAS (Shared Access Signatures) tokens that are NOT issued from a Stored Access Policy? In other words, I'd like to prevent Application Services from using ad-hoc access policies. That way, we not only manage the policies centrally, but we can quickly and with little impact revoke them.

I wish I could do all the reviews myself to ensure nobody does anything like that in the code, but I don't and not everyone does thorough code reviews. So I want to save us from ourselves.

Answer (score -1):

The only way is `change the account key`.

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy):

```
A shared access signature URI is associated with the account key used to create the     
signature, and the associated stored access policy (if any). If no stored access policy is     
specified, the only way to revoke a shared access signature is to change the account key.
```

Comment: Changing the account key eliminates application's access to storage account altogether. That's not desired. What the question is after is a way to distinguish tokens issued through a stored policy vs an ad-hoc one.

Comment: Yes, it has some bad effect. But as far as I know, there are no other ways to do it.